# Updating a variable inside another variable

Tags: php

I'm wondering if it is possible to update a variable which is inside another variable.

Here is an example:

```
$t = 15;
$dir ='foo and some more text'.$t.'and more foo';
$t = 10;
print_r($dir);
```

For me `$dir` outputs `$t` as 15 not as 10.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: No, the variable is evaluated when is is concatenated into the string

Comment: No, that’s not possible. Perhaps you want to look into what `sprintf` can do.

Answer (score 5):

You're misunderstanding what that code is actually doing.  This line:

```
$dir ='foo and some more text'.$t.'and more foo';
```

doesn't store a *reference* to `$t` for future evaluation.  It evaluates `$t` to whatever value it has *at that time* and uses the *result* to construct the value placed in `$dir`.  Any reference to `$t` is lost before the engine even gets to the step of assigning it to `$dir`.

You can pass a variable to a function, you can encapsulate variable state in an object, but an evaluated string doesn't reference a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. But you can make something similar with `preg_match` and a custom print function.

This is an just example how it could be done (warning: **experimental**):

```php
<?php

$blub = 15;
$test = 'foo and some more text %blub and more foo %%a';

function printv($text) {
    $parsedText = preg_replace_callback('~%([%A-Za-z0-9]+)~i', function($matches) {
        if ($matches[1][0] != '%') {
            return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]];
        }

        return $matches[1];
    }, $text);

    echo $parsedText;
}

$blub = 17;
printv($test);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever be the value of $t at the time of assigning $dir the value is 15. That will be stored and assigned. This is same for all the languages.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to, its easy to do it with [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
 $dir = function ($t) {return 'foo and some more text'.$t.'and more foo';}
 echo $dir(10);
 //foo and some more text10and more foo
 echo $dir(15);
 //foo and some more text15and more foo
```